# how to call executeFunc when page refresh

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest, jsom

I am working on Sharepoint JSOM with rest.

I am using search template for search. In that page also i have default sharepoint pagination for manage results.

So ,i have to call `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', load);` function when page load , page refresh or pagination click.

I have write code in load method.and call like below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', load);

});
```

Problem is occur while pagination because context load once.

So how we can execute load method when page load, refresh or pagination fired.

Thanks

Comment: You are using a Display Template for search?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `resultRendered`, it will be called every time the result changes, like pagination. The page doesn't trigger document.ready again when it paginate.

If you are using Display Template, you could add it in the Control template:

```
ctx.ClientControl.add_resultRendered(function() { 
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', load);
});
```

Or I guess you also could do something like this from your current javascripts:

```
$getClientControl( $("#Result").parent()[0] ).add_resultRendered(function() {  
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', load);
});
```

Just make that the result webpart is loaded before you run that one.